# How to plugin siddhi web editor within existing project?

Tags: customization, restriction, siddhi, pluggable

We are thinking to use Siddhi web editor. Can you please let us know how we can integrate siddhi web editor with our existing UI (Adapt Framework) and restrict few functionalities from editor. In short how we can customize the web editor and plug with our existing UI?

Answer (score 0):

Siddhi web editor is designed to be run on the OSGi environment with microservices. As of now, there is no way to customise the editor interface except jumping over the javascript code in Editor code in [io.siddhi.distribution.editor.core](https://github.com/siddhi-io/distribution/tree/master/tooling/components/io.siddhi.distribution.editor.core). Also, note that all components under [tooling](https://github.com/siddhi-io/distribution/tree/master/tooling) module should be present for the Editor to run correctly